# Swift Firebase get next Child data by pressing Button

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

How can I get the next child data from a firebase database by pressing a button?

```
import UIKit
```

import Firebase

class ViewController: UIViewController {

```
var ref: DatabaseReference!

@IBOutlet weak var textLabel: UILabel!
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    ref = Database.database().reference()

    ref.child("motivator").child("spruche").observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
        // Get user value
        let value = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary
        let username = value?["spruche1"] as? String ?? ""
        self.textLabel.text = username


        // ...
    }) { (error) in
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }


}
```

Comment: What do you mean by next ?? in same level of motivator or spruche ?

Comment: in same level like spruche

Comment: if you have the child name access it same way , what's problem in that ?

Comment: How do u mean that ? If I have like 10 or more Childs in spruche should I do write the same code over and over again ?

Comment: then write  ref.child("motivator").observeSingleEvent

Comment: @OzanGümüstas - try changing the `enum` for the property change observed. Right now you have it as `.value` which will return in any case where that entry has value. If you want to observe some sort of child added, without looking at the Firebase docs, I think it's actually just `.childAdded`

Comment: I tried it with .childAdded but it shows me nothing.I just only want that then I click on the button it should show me the next data.I don't know if that is possible with firebase but I didn't found a solution.